# Angular JS ng-form Email validation before the data binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, email

I have an Angular JS form as below:

```
<div ng-controller="EmpController as empVm"
 name="formEmployee" ng-form >
       <div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                Email
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <input type="email" validate-length ng-maxlength="2000"
                       ng-model="empVm.profileData.email" name="email"
                       ng-pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$"/>
                <div ng-show="(formEmployee.email.$dirty || formEmployee.email.$touched) && formEmployee.email.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="!formEmployee.email.$error.pattern">Invalid Email</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Even though the email field has the valid email the form is always invalid. Once I interact with the email text box like changing some text in the email text box the form is becoming valid again.

What I am trying to achieve is, the form should validate data for the email text box once the value is bind from the service call and form should be valid after the page load if it is valid email else form should be invalid and the above div which has the invalid email message should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data coming from the back end service call had a **space character** at the end of the email for which the regex failed and that space was not visible in the text box on UI and that's the reason why the form was becoming invalid.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `span` specifying `Invalid Email` is not closed.
2. The value in the `ng-pattern` should be an `$scope`/`vm` object or a raw string (i.e. between quotes).
3. The email pattern does not seem to be complete.
4. In your example, we don't know where `frmAgentProfile` comes from.
5. You are talking about a service call, we don't have any informations about that. If you want to validate from a service call, you should create a custom async validator.

I pushed your code in a fiddle where the `ng-pattern` works.

**[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/9ocnqfmm/)**